# Best way of converting tuple of uint32's to 3d numpy array of uint8's

Tags: python, numpy, javax.imageio

I've got image from external api presented as tuple of uint32s, where each uint32 consists of 4 uint8 with r, g, b and alpha (always = 0) and i need to convert it to 3d numpy array with format identical to what I can get from `imageio.imread`. Problem is that when I use `numpy.view` order of colors is inverted. This is code I've written that works OK, but I was wondering if there's better way of conversion.

```
        frame_buffer_tuple = ... # here we have tuple of width*height length
        framebuffer = np.asarray(frame_buffer_tuple).astype(dtype='uint32').view(dtype='uint8').reshape((height, width, 4)) # here I have height x width x 4 numpy array but with inverted colors (red instead of blue) and alpha I don't need
        framebuffer = np.stack((framebuffer[:, :, 2], framebuffer[:, :, 1], framebuffer[:, :, 0]), axis=2) # here I've got correct numpy height x width x 3 array
```

I'm more concerned about execution time, then memory, but since I can have 7680 × 4320 images, both may be important. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RichieV pointed me in right direction, actually what worked is:

```
framebuffer = np.asarray(frame_buffer_tuple).astype('uint32').view('uint8').reshape((height, width, 4))[:, :, 2::-1]
```

I'll mark this as solution for now, until someone comes up with even solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you only need to invert the last dimension? Try

```
framebuffer = framebuffer [:, :, :2:-1] # drops alpha
```

Comment: `framebuffer = np.asarray(frame_buffer_tuple).astype(dtype='uint32').view(dtype='uint8').reshape((height, width, 4))[:, :, :2:-1]` gave me only alpha (i.e. W x H x 1 array of zeros)

Comment: right `slice(None, 2, -1)` starts from the end and goes down until reaching index 2, it should start a index 2 and go down till the first element with `slice(2, None, -1)`